# Tor unexpectedly exited

Tags: 17.10, tor-browser

No Tor Log. I just upgraded it and restarted it. Now it's unlaunchable from launcher, and from command line it only opens up "Tor unexpectedly exited" window, and "restart tor" does not restart tor,  it just comes back to "Tor unexpectedly exited" over and over and over again. Obviously no settings were wrong, because I was using Tor fine before it upgraded itself.

[image]

One error I see that makes no sense:

> ...torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libevent-2.0.so.5 is in /Tor, not /Tor/tor, so why is it even trying to look inside /Tor/tor!?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix you can simply find another running tor browser process/es (which should be the cause of the problem) and kill it/them. Like:

```
$ps aux | grep tor
# find the process, it should be distinguishable from
#'monitors', 'grantors' etc, or fine tune the grep command
# above
# then kill the tor browser
$kill 1234
```

I have the same problem. It, seemingly, occurs, when I try to do some actions (probably restart) with the audit daemon. After them tor refuses to start.

I found this question, and thank you, you pointed to the fact, that the browser has all necessary libs with it. So then I manually fixed the command (i.e. pointed to the libs etc. correctly, tor reported an error that **another tor instance is running with the same data directory**. So I killed it and it fixed the issue temporarily.